# downloading an .eml attachment using exchange web services

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2010

I have a utility I built that checks an exchange email box and downloads attachments to a specified location.  However, I'm running into a bug with messages that have another email attached to them (in *.msg).  Whenever these pop up the attachments properties are not available so i can not access them to download them.:

[image: .msg attachment]

versus when a zip or something like that comes in:

[image: zip attachment]

is there away to detect that this is an .msg attachment?  or perhaps, "cast" it as such.  I know I can wrap this in a try catch but i dont want to fall over into converting the attachment to a .msg when perhaps it is another file type that it is causing this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Zach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just cleaning up my SO but here is how I solved this.  The eml attachment is actually an "ItemAttachment" instead of a "FileAttachment" versus the generic "Attachment."  So the loop looks like this:

```
  foreach (Attachment att in itm.Attachments)
  {
       if (att is FileAttachment)
       {
           var fileAttachment = att as FileAttachment;
           //do some stuff
       }
       else
       {
           var itemAttachment = att as ItemAttachment;
           //do some more stuff (these are most likely eml/msg attachments...
       }
  }
```